# How to check if a record is on 2 different tables?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and looking for an efficient way of handling this problem.

I have a `Sales` table which has a `User` reference column and an `Offer` reference  column.

The Sales table keeps track of which users came in to claim an offer (i.e. 10% discount).

So I have the following subclasses

```
Offers
Users
Sales
```

I want to display all available offers but set a local hasBeenUsed flag so that I can display the Offers differently if they have already been used.

At the moment I can create a local array of available Offers but I'm not sure how to set this hasBeenUsed flag accordingly.

```
var query = Message.query()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
 for object in objects {
  var offer = Offer()
  offer.info = object["info"] as String
  if (also on the Sales list)
   offer.hasBeenUsed = true
  }
  self.offers.insert(offer, atIndex: 0)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Caveat: Please pardon any Swift errors I make. I am still writing exclusively in Objective-C and I've tried my best to write good Swift, but I am not yet an expert in the syntax.***

The best answer I can come up with is that you'll need 2 queries (and this assumes you care about `Sales` for `[PFUser currentUser]` or `PFUser.currentUser()`):

1. Get the list of `Sales` objects for the current user
2. Get the list of all (current) `Offer` objects.

### Query 1

#### Swift Version

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Sales")
query.includeKey("Offer")
query.whereKey("User", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Assign the objects to a property or something
        self.sales = objects
        // **Then**, run query 2
        runQuery2()

    } else {
        // Do error handling...
    }
}
```

#### Objective-C Version

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Sales"];
[query includeKey:@"Offer"];
[query whereKey:@"User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Do error handling

    } else {
        // Assign the objects to a property or something...
        self.sales = objects;
        // **Then**, run query 2
        [self runQuery2];

    }
}
 ];
```

### Query 2

#### Swift Version

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Offers")
// Whatever query constraints you need to get "current" offers
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Assign the objects to a property or something
        self.offers = objects;
        // At this point, you have all the data you need, so call the "filter" method
        filter()

    } else {
        // Do error handling...
    }
}
```

#### Objective-C Version

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Offers"];
// Whatever query constraints you need to get "current" offers
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Do error handling

    } else {
        // Assign the objects to a property or something
        self.offers = objects;
        // At this point, you have all the data you need, so call the "filter" method
        [self filter];

    }

}
 ];
```

### Filter Method

***This assumes 2 properties: "sales", an array of sales for the current user, and "offers", an array of all current offers***

#### Swift Version

```
// First, get all of the "redeemed" offers into an array
var localOffers = [PFObject]()
for sale in self.sales {
    localOffers.append(sale.offer)
    // It might be easier to do it this way
    // localOffers.append(sale.offer.objectId)
}

// Next, iterate the "all offers" array and mark each offer as redeemed/not redeemed
for offer in self.offers {
    if (localOffers.containsObject(offer)) {
    // Alternative check
    // if (localOffers.containsObject(offer.objectId)) {
        offer.hasBeenUsed = true
    } else {
        offer.hasBeenUser = false
    }
}
```

#### Objective-C Version

```
// First, get all of the "redeemed" offers into an array
NSMutableArray *localOffers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (PFObject *sale in self.sales) {
    [localOffers addObject:sale.offer];
    // It might be easier to do it this way
    // [localOffers addObject:self.offer.objectId];
}

// Next, iterate the "all offers" array and mark each offer as redeemed/not redeemed
for (PFObject *offer in self.offers) {
    if ([localOffers containsObject:offer]) {
    // Alternative check
    // if ([localOffers containsObject:offer.objectId]) {
        offer[@"hasBeenUsed"] = @(YES);
    } else {
        offer[@"hasBeenUsed"] = @(NO);
    }
}
```

At this point, you've got what you need to display the data differently based upon whether the offer has been redeemed or not. Just be careful not to save the `hasBeenUsed` values to Parse **unless that's what you intend**.